# Pcregrep using matching groups

Tags: regex, perl, bash, grep

I want to use a simple bash syntax to grep numbers from a range. E.g. from the phrase

`range "7.2-55.0"`

I want to save **start=7.2** and **end=55.0**.

Because I know some perl regex (pcre), I tried:

```
echo 'range "7.2-55.0"' | pcregrep -o '^range \"(\S+)\"'
echo 'range "7.2-55.0"' | pcregrep -o '^range \"([0-9.-]+)\"'
```

which isn't working. The output is the whole line. So what is my fault? And is it possible to save 2 matching groups with `pcregrep`?

While searching the web I found e.g. `pcregrep -o1` but I seem to have another version of the tool, because I am only allowed to use `-o` option (GNU Bash-3.2).

Comment: Not matching anything. And what does the `\K` stands for?

Comment: Btw. is `grep -P` the same as `pcregrep`?

Comment: Not a pcregrep expert, but it seems that it has no feature to return only the first capturing group. From the [man page](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?pcregrep), the `-o` option only makes it return the line where it found a match - and your match here is the whole line anyway.

Comment: @Robin maybe there are different versions then, because I saw the `-o1` and `-o2` options in examples online. Btw. I found that `pcregrep` should be faster than `grep -P` or `grep -E`.

Comment: This is where I start to look at doing the whole thing in perl, awk, whatever, so that I don't have to run many multiples of commands to extract all the details (one set of subprocesses for each value).

Answer (score 1):

You can do like this with `awk`

```
start=$(echo 'range "7.2-55.0"' | awk -F'["-]' '/range/ {print $2}')
end=$(echo 'range "7.2-55.0"' | awk -F'["-]' '/range/ {print $3}')
echo $start
7.2
echo $end
55.0
```

Comment: +1 that is working, thx. Though it is quite restrictive in defining the match. And I would still be interested why the grep isn't working.

Comment: You could add a search pattern to make sure it take correct line, like `awk -F'["-]' '/range/{print $2}'`.  Can not help you with `grep` sorry.

Comment: Thx once again, also didn't know of this search pattern!